# Tensorboard for API 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-serving

In the old versions, we can use this command after the creating the network structure and creating the session.

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("logs/", sess.graph)
```

And type this in the cmd after running your script:

```
tensorboard --logdir="logs"
```

Then you copy the link to your browser.

But it shows this error:

> No graph definition files were found.
>
> To store a graph, create a tf.summary.FileWriter and pass the graph
>   either via the constructor, or by calling its add_graph() method. You
>   may want to check out the graph visualizer tutorial .1

Please help. I also tried using the tf.summary.FileWriter() instead

```
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/path/to/logs', sess.graph)
```

And I get the same error.

Comment: Did you actually use the writer to write anything? Did you close() or flush() it?

Comment: No sir, where can I found the documentation for this? It's not in the tensorboard tutorial in the tensorflow website.

Comment: @MadWombat all I want to do is to view the graph.

Comment: I'm a total beginner

Comment: @MadWombat I'm using this code https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf14_tensorboard/full_code.py

Comment: Exactly what command are you typing to run `tensorboard`? (In particular, does the `--logdir` flag value contain `C:\`?)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with the folder you are writing to, or reading from. After you tried the filewriter, can you verify that it indeed wrote something to your logs folders?

If this is the case, start your tensorboard with this command:

```
tensorboard --logdir="logs" --debug
```

Take a look at this line:

```
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is: {'/Users/test/logs': None}
```

Verify that this is the same path! This is what went wrong for me when I had the same issue. More debug ideas can be found on this page by the way: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md#my-tensorboard-isnt-showing-any-data-whats-wrong

If this does not help, let us know!

Comment: I changed the code to: summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:\\Users\\juv3r\\logs', sess.graph)

Comment: since the cmd outputted: INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is: {'C:\\Users\\juv3r\\logs': None}

Comment: But still the same